# Displaying differences with PowerPivot

Tags: pivot-table, dax

Based on the following Data:

```
Location    Salesperson Category    SalesValue
North       Bill        Bikes       10
South       Bill        Bikes       90
South       Bill        Clothes     250
North       Bill        Accessories 20
South       Bill        Accessories 20
South       Bob         Bikes       200
South       Bob         Clothess    400
North       Bob         Accesories  40
```

I have the following Sales PivotTable in Excel 2016

```
             Bill   Bob
Bikes        100    200
Clothes       10    160
Accessories   40     40
```

I would now like to diplay the difference between Bill and Bob and, importantly, be able to sort the table by difference. I have tried adding the Sales a second time and displaying it as a difference to "Bill". This gives me the correct values but sorts according to the underlying sales value and not the computed difference.

```
            Bill    Bob   Difference
Bikes        100    200          100
Clothes       10    160          150
Accessories   40     40            0
```

I am fairly sure I need to use some form of DAX calculation but am having difficulty finding out exactly how. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure for that calculation:

If Bill and Bob are columns in your table.

```
Difference = ABS(TableName[Bill] - TableName[Bob])
```

If Bill and Bob are measures:

```
Difference = ABS([Bill] - [Bob])
```

**UPDATE:** Expression to only calculate difference between Bob and Bill.

Create a measure (in this case `DifferenceBillAndBob`) and use the following expression.

```
DifferenceBillAndBob =
ABS (
    SUMX ( FILTER ( Sales, Sales[SalesPerson] = "Bob" ), [SalesValue] )
        - SUMX ( FILTER ( Sales, Sales[SalesPerson] = "Bill" ), [SalesValue] )
)
```

It is not tested but should work.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have a column called "salesperson" in a table called "Sales".

Comment: @BarneyW, update your question  and include a sample of your data table. Is there only two sales person or you want to show only Bill and Bob differences?

Comment: Thanks alejandro, there could be more salespeople but for the moment I am just interested in the diference between Bob and Bill

Comment: Excellent and very quick!

Comment: @BarneyW, if my answer solved your issue you can select it as the correct answer. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)